# codelite GCC switch and linker setup

Tags: gcc, linker

I'm trying to setup codelite using the GCC compiler. I'm trying to add the switches:

-fno-pie  -no-pie

This works when using gcc in the terminal.

Below is where I have placed the switches.I have done this for the cross GCC (i686) aswell.

[image: -fno-pie and -no-pie are added]

This doesn't seem to be working though. My disassembly doesn't seem to be the same as when I use gcc in my terminal to compile with the -fno-pie and -no-pie

How do I get this to work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have gone from the IDE's top menubar through **Settings** -> **Build Settings** -> **Compilers** -> *GCC* -> **Compiler Options** -> **New...**, and added options
`-fno-pie` and `-no-pie`

What you have done is edited the global compiler options for GCC that CodeLite will *make available* to be enabled or disabled
in the **Compiler options** dialog of any project that uses the GCC compiler. *You have not actually enabled either of those
options for any particular project that uses GCC*.

The globally configured compiler options for GCC (or other compiler) are by default the
most commonly wanted ones. There is no *need* to edit this configuration to use any
other compiler options in a project. If you *do* edit the configuration to make them
available, then you also need to *enable* them in the project **Settings** of GCC projects
in which you want them enabled.

`-fpie|-fno-pie` are compilation options. `-pie|-no-pie` are not compilation options: they are
linkage options. If you wanted to make these linkage options *available* in all GCC projects
then you would proceed through **Settings** -> **Build Settings** -> **Compilers** -> *GCC* -> **Linker Options** -> **New...**

To add `-fno-pie` to the compiler settings of a GCC project `MyProj`, from the workspace
tree-view, navigate *MyProj* -> **Settings** -> *{Debug|Release}* -> **Compiler** -> **{C++|C} Compiler Options**.

Then, if you have *not* bothered to edit the GCC compiler options configuration, just
edit the edit-field on the right - probably already containing default compiler options such
as `-g;-O0;-Wall` - and append `;-fno-pie` to whatever is there. If you *have* bothered
to add `-fno-pie` to the configured compiler options, then click on the '...' button
at the right of the edit-field, and select `-fno-pie` from the **Compiler Options**.

To add `-no-pie` to the linker settings of a GCC project `MyProj`, from the workspace
tree-view, navigate *MyProj* -> **Settings** -> *{Debug|Release}* -> **Linker** -> **Linker Options**
and apply `-no-pie` in the same way as you applied `-fno-pie` for the compiler options.

Comment: Sorry the late response! Thanks for the reply. I've been doing other things in the meantime. I'll try solution. thanks!